# Check if class is active twig

Tags: twig

I have a twig file with and `<ul>` and 3 `<li>` inside. One of them (the first) has a `class="active"`. That first one will be `display: none;` sometimes and when that happens, I want the second one to have the `class="active"`. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Also what triggers the first one's style to become set to `none`? Maybe `onmousedown`?

Comment: @AlvinBunk so far nothing triggers the first style to become none... I tried the twig if statement to do it, but the variable I'm trying to use isn't working in this file (even tho it's used in other twig file in the project). It's a percentage var created in php and the goal is: if that percentage is under x%, the style is not displayed

Comment: @AlvinBunk I assume I need to pass that var to twig somehow, but I'm not quite sure how

Comment: You should post the code you tried, otherwise no one here will help you!

Comment: @AlvinBunk Well I tried helping. but u are right he should post more info becouse now it just comes down as "how do I use an PHP var in twig"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on a project I once did. I presume your php is not in the same file.
You can try this thing.
There is an extends tag in twig. If im correct this works on `.twig / .html / .php` file extensions.

**This would be inside your PHP file**

```
{% extends "twigfile.twig" %}
{% block PHP %}

$yourvar = "'something'";

{% set yourtwigvar = $yourvar %}

{% endblock %}
```

**And then this would be inside your TWIG file**

```
{% block PHP %} 

{% set yourtwigvar = 'something' %}

{% endblock %}
```

If you use it like that you can write your other twig statements under the block and u can use the variable there.